# Coding Help Regarding Meta Tag And Site Title

Tags: php, html, meta

Hello Guys I need a small help pls Check this code

> print ' File Name: '.translit($file).' Video Song

in this code .translit($file). is name of my file and i want to show this file name in my site page title meta tag and also in meta keywords..

and when i am adding this code into

```
echo "<title>.translit($file). </title>";
```

it showing code as it is..

m newbie pls givvme sloution of this

Comment: We'd need to see a lot more of your code to diagnose the problem. At a minimum, assuming translit() is a valid function, your code should probably look like this: `echo "<title>" . translit($file) .  "</title>";`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to close the strings before concatenating them ie:

```
 echo "<title>".translit($file)."</title>";
```

Comment: thanks solved god bless u